# Retrieve triples with properties restricted by namespace

Tags: sparql

Given a resource `http://foo.com/res1` that is the subject of several of triples with properties from two different ontologies:

```
<http://foo.com/res1> dc:author <http://ppl.com/bob>
<http://foo.com/res1> dc:title "some resource"
<http://foo.com/res1> foaf:depiction <http://flickr.com/picture/1234>
```

I want to obtain all the triples with properties in the `dc` namespace and ignore all others.  How can I do this?

Comment: Thanks, I am voting to close the question as it seems I was searching for restricting to "ontology" and not "namespace".

Comment: Since you posted it, you can actually delete the question, if you want.  Having duplicates (but closed as such) around isn't bad through, because now if someone else searches and uses "ontologies" instead of namespaces, they'll find this one, and get pointed to the other question.  You can also flag the question for moderator attention, too, if you don't have enough rep to cast a close vote.

Comment: I flagged the question and explained your point. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using the XPath [`starts-with` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-starts-with):

```
SELECT * 
WHERE {
    <http://foo.com/res1> ?p ?o .
    FILTER(fn:starts-with(STR(?p),"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/")).
}
```

It fetches all triples for `<http://foo.com/res1>`, but includes only the ones that have a predicate whose string representation starts with `http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/`.

Comment: A good alternative, thank you. I seem to have missed a thread where this was already answered... bad searching on my part.

Comment: SPARQL 1.1 has a keyword for this `STRSTARTS`.