# Get all ontologies and values for a specific prefix

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

If I run this query:

```
SELECT ?subject
WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Oslo> dcterms:subject ?subject. }
```

I get this:

[image]

Which is correct. But I want all values in dbprop. So this part:

[image]

So a pseudo code that doesn't work would be:

```
SELECT ?properties
WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Oslo> dbprop:* ?properties. }
```

Expected result would be then each property (like `dbpprop:aprRecordHighC`) and it's value (like `25.400000`).

Is that possible?

Comment: Have a look at [Retrieve triples with properties restricted by namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18831007/1281433) and [SPARQL - Restricting Result Resource to Certain Namespace(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9597981/1281433).  Just note that `dbpprop:` is a prefix for `http://dbpedia.org/property/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
If you want all the properties and values given the "Oslo" resource, you should issue the following query:

```
SELECT ?property ?value
WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Oslo> ?property ?value. }
```

If you only want the dbprop properties, you can add a filter:

```
SELECT ?property ?value
WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Oslo> ?property ?value 
FILTER regex(str(?property), "http://dbpedia\\.org/property/")}
```

I have tried both of these queries in the [dbpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) and they worked.

You can find more information in the SPARQL specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#func-str

Edit: apparently, from the comments I see that this question has been answered previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9597981/1281433)

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [SPARQL - Restricting Result Resource to Certain Namespace(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9597981/1281433).  This use of `regex` isn't great because you're not specifically matching the beginning of the URI string (the answer to the other question does).  Additionally, in SPARQL 1.1, there's a `strstarts` function that's even better, as it doesn't do any regular expression testing.  Do you know offhand whether the `.` in your regex match a literal `.` or are wildcards?

Comment: oops I hadn't noticed the duplicate question, sorry. The sparql 1.1 suggestion is great, thanks! But I don't get your last question. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: `.` is a meta-character in most regular expression dialects (including SPARQL) meaning *match any character* so your query as written would also match a property like `http://dbpediaXorg/property` (not that such a property would exist in DBPedia itself).  To restrict it to literal `.` characters you need to use `"http://dbpedia\\.org/property/"` - backslash is the escape character for regular expressions but since it is also the escape character for SPARQL strings it needs double escaping in a SPARQL query

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Good point about the `.` meta-character, I have gone back and updated my original answer to correct it to account for this.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying it our, @RobV. I guess that I didn't realize because in this case they only have one property that matches the literal. I'll edit the response appropriately.

Comment: Thanks Guys! So the following query is what I want then: 
SELECT ?property ?value
WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Oslo> ?property ?value
FILTER(STRSTARTS(STR(?property), "http://dbpedia.org/property"))}

Comment: @MariusLian Code is not readable in comments, especially if you don't put it in backticks `\`like this\``.  As written in your comment, that's not what you want for a query, because `STRSTARTS(STR(?property), "dbpedia.org/property")` won't work right, since the property URI string will actually start with a leading `http://`.